# how do kick of Android JUnit Test in automated build?

Tags: android, junit, hudson

An Android JUnit test uses the Android Context object so it needs to get this from a device or emulator. Does anyone know how one could automate this? Would there need to be an emulator on the build machine? Any sample script would be helpful, and I would like to know how folks are doing this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can install and execute your unit test project from the command prompt using ant.

First update your already existing project

```
$ android update project --path $PWD --name [YOUR PROJECT] --target android-17 --subprojects
```

Then create a test project

```
$ android create test-project -m ../ -n [YOUR TEST PROJECT] -p tests
```

Then you can build and execute the code by issuing

```
$ ant clean instrument
$ ant debug install test
```

Cheers!